# Cocoa: in a document-based application, where does one store prefs for each document?

Tags: nsdocument

When making a document-based application, each document could have settings associated with it: sort order, split view size, window size, font size, etc.  Some of these I can see getting wrapped in with window restoration, but others seem awkward for that.

Is there a canon way to store preferences on a per-document basis?  I'm used to NSUserDefaults but those are app-wide; I've never done this for an NSDocument app.